# Password Protection of an alpha website

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web

I am currently working on a website but now, it is currently in pre-alpha stage and so I do not want people to sign up. Is there any way to avoid people signing other than obscuring the sign up button/link?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll usually just need to make sure your `UsersController`'s `create` action doesn't do anything.